# every vertex of odd degree is the startpoint of a path that also ends in a vertex of odd degree

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove the following.

if u is a vertex of odd degree in a graph, then there exists a path from u to another vertex v of the graph were v also has odd degree.

I have no idea where to start with this.  I understand that a path is a sequence from a vertex along an edge to another vertex but I am not sure how to start this proof.  Could someone help guide me with the start?

Thanks,

Comment: Hint. Start traversing the graph from $u$. Each time you get to a vertex, leave it by an edge you haven't used before. Think about whether you will ever get stuck and be unable to move. Also look up Euler's solution to the Bridges of Konigsberg problem.

Comment: Perhaps more care should go into the definition of a "chain" if it is intended that this means a *path* that doesn't repeat any edge.

Comment: my text refers to a path as only applying to digraphs and a chain is then applied to graphs.  Path meaning it is 1 directional and chain then meaning 2 directional.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose otherwise, that is that every path which begins with $u$ ends at a vertex with even degree.

We know that for every vertex in $u$'s connected component, there is a path from $u$ to that vertex.  Then every vertex within the same connected component as $u$ is of even degree except for $u$.

> The subgraph consisting only of the connected component of $u$ however must satisfy the handshaking lemma that $2|E|=\sum\limits_{v\in V}\deg(v)$ and its corollary that every graph must have an even number of odd-degree vertices.

$~$

> This is, however, a contradiction as there was to be only one vertex of odd degree (*namely u*) in *u*'s connected component.